# Trying to update an ASP.Net MVC 1.0 project to MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-2, httpcontext

I'm trying to update my project to ASP.Net MVC 2.0 from MVC 1.0.  I've removed the references for System.Web.MVC to the newer versions.  I'm getting an exception from the HTTPContext which reads "CurrentNotification = 'HttpContext.Current.CurrentNotification' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'".  What other binaries do I need to update a reference to, to get my project to work again?

Comment: @Cptcecil: I didn't know there was an "MVC 1.0" and an "MVC 2.0", that's kinda funny :)   *(I only knew about several types of MVC, including "MVC type 2")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown because

> The operation requires integrated pipeline mode in IIS 7.0 and at least the .NET Framework version 3.0.

and may not be related to ASP.NET MVC 2.0.